# which is a good library to read and write MS excel files with Python 3

Tags: excel, python-3.x

Which can be mature libraries to use with python 3.3+
I looked on xlutils but that is only for python 2.x while others don't look stable or are abandoned

Answer (score 5):

You can try [DataNitro](http://datanitro.com), which supports Python 3.

Source: I'm one of the DataNitro developers.